# showing full background image in div tag in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using bootstrap to develop website. My website content - 3 fixed columns which consists of left side menu, center content, right side menu and also top banner. I want to display the full background image in center content which is a blank div tag only. My problem is the background image don't fully covered the content and only a half of the image is shown. 
I have the following code in html and css :

**index.html**

```
<div class="img-responsive content_area"></div>
```

**style.css**

```
.content_area {
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/bg.png) no-repeat top left;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post a more complete example using something like http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Here ..http://jsfiddle.net/3efxuvzv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/3efxuvzv/4/

CSS

```
.content_area {
    width:100%;
    padding-top: 74.6691871456%;
    background: url(http://www.postfree108.com/images_postfree/Direct-marketing-12890.jpg) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: cover;
}
.content {
    margin-top: -74.6691871456%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="content_area">
    <div class="content">
        <!-- put your content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Essentially, I put the actual html content in another wrapper, and used the fact that percentages for padding and margins even for top/bottom are calculated by the width of the element, to set a padding-top of the aspect ratio of your image (`74.6691871456% = 395/529` - the dimensions of your background image), then on the content element offset the padding using negative the same amount of margin. Effectively this creates a min-height kind of effect based on your desired aspect ratio.