# Add background image in a div without empty space between div and footer

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to create a webpage. I created a page with 1 horizontal nav bar, header and then a division for the body content and a vertical bar in the left side, and then the footer.
I would like to add a image in the background, but only in the body division that I created (col-lg-10). Which is the best way? I want the image covering all this division, for example http://www.bootply.com/62096 The problem is, I tried to add the image, but there was an empty space between the div and the footer.

Here is my code - https://jsfiddle.net/clarissab/23kcck71/

My CSS code

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
#header {
  background-color: #4C6F85;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.nav-custom a {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

My Html code

```
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Name company</a>
      </div>

      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Address</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <ul class="breadcrumb lighterbgcolor">
          <li class="location">HOME</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div id="header" class="col-lg-12">
      <h2><strong>Title</strong></h2>
    </div>


    <div id="sideLeft" class="col-lg-2">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-custom nav-stacked">
        <BR>
        <BR>

        <li class="nav-link active"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Goals</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <div id="body2" class="col-lg-10" style="padding-left:100px; padding-right:300px;">
      <BR>
      <h4 class="text-justify">blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</h4>
      <BR>
      <h4 class="text-justify">blaablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</h4>
      <BR>
      <h4 class="text-justify">blablablablablablabla</h4>
      <BR>
      <h4 class="text-justify">blablablablablablabla</h4>
      <BR>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="footer" class="col-lg-12">

  </div>

</body>
```

I tried to add in the CSS, the code above, but did not cover all div until the footer.

```
#body2 { background-image: url('xx.jpg');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:79%;
        height: 740px;
                                }
```

Comment: Did not look good, or did not work? You need to be more specific about what you're asking.

Comment: Like this?: https://jsfiddle.net/23kcck71/5/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [showing full background image in div tag in bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613802/showing-full-background-image-in-div-tag-in-bootstrap)

Comment: @BenM The image was not covering the entire division, so I tried to increase the height, but still there was a space between the division and the footer division.

Comment: @LGSon, yes, but the image is not covering the space until the footer...

Comment: Well in your case you set a bottom margin on the body, `body { margin-bottom: 120px; }`, but footer is only 60px high. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/23kcck71/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following css for background-size. First target the div you want the background. Example:

```
 body{
   ...
   background-size: cover;
   */or/*
   backgroun-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;

 }
```

contain might fit the whole image inside your div, but might not cover the whole div. Cover, might not show parts of image since you are covering whole div. Another option might be `background-size:100% 100%;`

Answer (score 1):

Put the background url in quotes.

It should be `background: url('background.png');`

Comment: Yes I did it, but did not cover all the div